# The radiation power of an electromagnetic wave scatter due to the magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering

In studying the scattering of an electromagnetic wave by a single charge, it seems typically we consider the motion driven only by the electric field, as is presented in [Section 32-5 Scattering of Light of the Feynman Lectures on Physics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_32.html#Ch32-S5). But the charge speed is not zero. So it has an additional acceleration due to the magnetic field of the light wave. I suppose the power contribution from that acceleration is minute and thus can be ignored. I would like to see an exact computation taking the magnetic field contribution into account or at least a bound on that contribution. Would anyone care to provide either a computation or references of that computation?

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz force acting on the charged particle is

$$
\mathbf F = q\mathbf E + q\mathbf v\times \mathbf B
$$
where $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ are external fields at the position of the particle.

In case these fields are due to a plane EM wave, or a spherical EM wave of a localized remote source, magnitudes of these fields are related in this way:

$$
|\mathbf B| = |\mathbf E|/c.
$$
where $c$ is speed of light in vacuum. This can be derived from Maxwell's equations.

We can see the magnetic force due to EM wave is proportional to velocity of the charged particle $\mathbf v$, while the electric force is not. Thus for non-relativistic particles, the electric force obviously dominates. This is the case for electrons bound in light atoms in ordinary material bodies, so scattering off them does not involve substantial magnetic force, unless the electrons get relativistic as a result of interaction with the EM wave - which they do if the wave has high enough frequency (X-ray, gamma). Very heavy atoms may have some relativistic electrons too.

However, it seems useful to point out that this criterion depends on the frame of reference we use to describe the charged particle motion. In EM wave scattering problems, we often consider the charged particle to be still or moving only non-relativistically. But we can always mentally jump into a frame where the particle does have relativistic speed, and the magnetic force may become substantial there, depending on the angle between the relativistic velocity and magnetic field vector.

In some cases, we do not need to change the frame at all. There are relativistic electrons circling in synchrotrons, or coming out of radioactive nuclei, or (as mentioned above) coming out of atomic electron shells due to gamma radiation scattering. Such relativistic electrons scatter EM waves too, and magnetic part of the EM force is likely relevant even in the laboratory frame. For example, if the electron moves relativistically with speed close to $c$ in the same direction as the EM wave, the electric and the magnetic force are almost the same, so they both contribute to electron's acceleration in the same way.

Comment: Can you provide any references for the situations described in paragraph 3 and 2?

Comment: Also, would you care to look at my other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/781785/17354?

Comment: Re paragraphs 2,3, I meant standard textbook stuff, try Griffiths *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, Landau & Lifshitz *The classical theory of fields*, Jackson *Classical electrodynamics*, for more detailed book on radiation Marion *Classical electromagnetic radiation*.

Comment: Regarding examples of magnetic force being important, see Marion's book, sections 10.5 Wave propagation in plasma, 10.6. Zeeman effect.

Comment: Just to clarify, with regard to your paragraph 2, I am not asking how to perform a Lorentz transform on a field which I know perfectly. I am asking for treatment of the magnetic field. Do the references of Landau & Lifshitz simply perform such a treatment? Would you be so kind to point out the specific sections in those references such as Landau & Lifshitz and Jackson that deal with the magnetic factor? Chapter 16 of Jackson on point charge radiation seems not to have taken the magnetic component of the incoming wave into account. Of course I might have missed it.

Comment: I checked out section 10.5 and 10.6 of Marion. It appears that both are examining the charged particle motion in an external static magnetic field rather than an incoming plane EM wave. So it does not answer my question.

Comment: I think magnetic force is routinely dismissed in calculations of classical scattering off electrons with the simple argument that magnitude of this force relative to electric force is small. I don't know of a source which studies specifically effects of magnetic force in this type of scattering, this seems like a topic that could have been addressed in some specialized papers.

Comment: This is probably also because EM wave scattering off electrons is a subject that is studied in a more modern way using quantum electrodynamics (Klein-Nishina formula...), where concepts like electric/magnetic force do not play a role, instead it's about Hamiltonians, Lagrangians, propagators, Feynman diagrams, path integrals etc. Compton scattering is formally similar to Doppler effect so non-expert on this topic can hypothesize that in some sense velocity of the scattering electrons is taken into account. But better study papers and books on Compton scattering to get reliable info on this.

Comment: According to account here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5709540/ the Klein-Nishina theory takes into account electronic spins, and this predicts elliptical polarization of the scattered wave. So in their theory it is plausible that effect of magnetic interaction is taken into account (as spins are usually interacting magnetically, not electrically).

Comment: "magnetic force is routinely dismissed ... with the simple argument that magnitude ... relative to electric force is small." This is exactly what I said in the question and I was asking for a proof of that folkloric statement and a bound for the magnetic component. The formalisms of QED such Lagrangians are composed of the field tensors which are electromagnetic fields. So it is not true the latter are not used. Thank you for the Klein-Nishina formula reference. I suppose it consists of the first couple of terms of Feynman path integral.